# Polyfilling node_modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, polyfills

I am successfully using Babel 6 for all my ES2015 needs in my own codebase but I have found instances of `Object.assign` in `fluxible-addons-react` and `String.prototype.repeat` in `react-relay`. Yahoo dropped internal polyfill support [here](https://github.com/yahoo/fluxible/blob/5218d512ee547a5032a87025b2194877995db55e/packages/fluxible-addons-react/CHANGELOG.md). And I am not sure whether Facebook ever supported a polyfill internally.

I discovered when booting my relay app in Safari 8 that I had to...

```
// Polyfill for Fluxible*
Object.assign = require('core-js/library/fn/object/assign');
// Polyfill for Relay
String.prototype.repeat = require('core-js/library/fn/string/repeat');
```

Does it make more sense to just...

```
require('babel-polyfill');
```

In which case we end up with a possibly higher overhead and superfluous polyfilling in the more modern browsers, but...hunting for the needed polyfills in my browser support matrix and supporting them one by on via `core-js` seeems a bit madness-inducing.

Does anybody else with experience in this area have recommendations for feedback?

Comment: *"superfluous polyfilling in the more modern browsers"* What do you mean by that? If a browser supports something natively, there is no need for a polyfill. Polyfills only fill what's missing.

Answer (score 0):

Once I realized that babel-polyfill wraps core-js anyway, this became a non-question.

https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/e68754faf246ba2f7624380d24e7ff369e7caf06/packages/babel-polyfill/package.json#L11